# File name too long mount_nfs

Tags: freebsd, mount, vagrant

I have a FreeBSD Vagrant box that looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "chef/freebsd-10.0"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', :nfs => true, id: "vagrant-root"

end
```

However, if it tries to run in a directory path with too long a name it fails:

```
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -t nfs '10.0.1.1:/Users/petersouter/projects/reallylongpathnameover88characterssothatmountfswillfail12345678910111213141516' '/vagrant'

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount_nfs: 10.0.1.1:/Users/petersouter/projects/reallylongpathnameover88characterssothatmountfswillfail12345678910111213141516: File name too long
```

Is there a way to resolve this other than copying the directory to one with a shorter name? Can I update FreeBSD stuff so it can accept larger file names?

Comment: Why is the paths' name that long? Normally you try to avoid those big lengths.

Comment: paths with meaning are often very long.  unix legacy is about short stuff

Comment: I got this issue too in Kubernetes NFS volumes with FreeNAS, any idea or solutions?

Comment: Looks like this ended up being fixed in FreeBSD12... so I guess try to update your NAS to a newer version? https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FreeBSD limits the length of mount point names to 88 chars.  The reasons for this are somewhat esoteric, but has to do with aligning a memory structure on page boundaries[1].

You can patch the mount binary to use a larger limit or to remove it all together[2] but this may cause crashes.  I have successfully removed the check (also for vagrant with nfs) and had it work without problems, but do so at your own risk.  I did not do a full buildworld but rebuilt only the mount_nfs binary with the patch from the second link.

As a final note, I eventually decided that vagrant with nfs is too buggy and switched to using rsync shared folders instead.

[1] http://www.secnetix.de/olli/FreeBSD/mnamelen.hawk

[2] https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167105